# Is cache invalidation policy for logged-in users changed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, caching

Today, I noticed that some question pages were served from cache and the vote counts and my reputation displayed on the top bar were not up to date. Of course, I was logged in. I don't think I had experienced this behavior before. This is a little irritating. Anyone else noticed? Is there anything changed on StackOverflow or my ISP is caching aggressively to save their bandwidth or it's an issue with Google Chrome?

Comment: I don't think it's just you - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/unable-to-vote-on-an-old-question-due-to-vote-too-old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this was a dumb error in our settings. Fixed many hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yerp, I'm also getting this on Google Chrome, my isp is in aussie and they do not cache too aggressively. Its probably an issue with haproxy or something.

When I go back to SO main site after a few hour of inactivity, it looks like I'm not logged in, a prompt reload of the page fixes stuff up.